# Converting a C# method to use generics referencing a property inside

Tags: c#, linq, generics, c#-3.0, foreach

I would like to convert a method to use generics.
It is currently hard-coded to these types:

- `DataContext.Document` in the data context's partial class and inheriting from `object`
- `DataContext.Documents` also in this partial class and inheriting from `Linq.Table<Document>`
- `Import.Document` inheriting from a custom class `ImportObject`

**Original method:**

```
public void ProcessDocuments(Delegate method, params object[] args)
{
    using (DataContext dc = new DataContext())
    {
        dc.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;

        // Map from DataContext object to ImportObject
        Mapper.CreateMap<Document, Import.Document>();

        // Loop through DataContext objects
        foreach (Document d in dc.Documents)
        {
            Import.Document doc = Mapper.Map<Document, Import.Document>(d);
            args[0] = doc;
            method.DynamicInvoke(args);
        }
    }
}
```

**Attempted method:**

```
public void ProcessImportObjects<TSource, TDestination>
    (Action<TDestination, ImportDataSource, int> processMethod, ImportDataSource importSource, int resultId)
{
    using (DataContext dc = new DataContext())
    {
        dc.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;
        Mapper.CreateMap<TSource, TDestination>();

        foreach (TSource d in dc.Documents) // PROBLEM: Hard-coded reference to property on DataContext
        {
            TDestination doc = Mapper.Map<TSource, TDestination>(d);
            processMethod(doc, importSource, resultId);
        }
    }
}
```

(Here, `TDestination` should be of type `ImportObject` but I'm not sure how to express that.)

As shown in the comment, **the foreach needs to reference a property on the DataContext that is an `IEnumerable<TSource>`**.
Does this mean I need to pass the DataContext in as a parameter or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to parameterize the property name in `DataContext`. One way to do it is to pass in a function that takes a `DataContext` and returns your enumerable (a `Func<DataContext, IEnumerable<TSource>>`) and then you would pass in a lambda like `dc => dc.Document` as that parameter.

Another option, which would work (but without type-safety) is to pass in the property's name as a string and then use Reflection to access it.

```
public void ProcessImportObjects<TSource, TDestination>
    (Func<DataContext, IEnumerable<TSource>> dcProperty,
     Action<TDestination, ImportDataSource, int> processMethod,
     ImportDataSource importSource,
     int resultId)
{
    using (DataContext dc = new DataContext())
    {
        dc.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;
        Mapper.CreateMap<TSource, TDestination>();

        foreach (TSource d in dcProperty(dc))
        {
            TDestination doc = Mapper.Map<TSource, TDestination>(d);
            processMethod(doc, importSource, resultId);
        }
    }
}
```